# How am I able to create a Restart Config instead of the start config (.vscode)

Tags: node.js, express, visual-studio-code

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\main.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the config for the launch of the website. Is there a way to make a restart config or script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this source on [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_restarting-debug-sessions-automatically-when-source-is-edited) website and i think its exactly what you want.

first install [nodemon](https://nodemon.io/) on your machine with

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

then use this configuration

```
{
    "name": "Launch server.js via nodemon",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.js",
    "restart": true,
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
}
```

Comment: Would this work once running on my server computer and being hosted? I want to make sure it autorestarts if i change anything.

Comment: @Messivert yes it will definitely work whenever there is a change on your hosted code it will restart node. check their [FAQ](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/faq.md) about production usage section but i wouldn't recommend using nodemon on a production server.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only do this for local development you can try

[bdspen/nodemon_vscode](https://github.com/bdspen/nodemon_vscode) which uses [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) alternatively in production you can configure nodemon from package.json, in order to restart app when fail etc. Also worth mention [Forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) here.